# Parse Query Get Data To List

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have a list parameter **List list** that I am trying to pass the sList back to.  How do I get the data to the super class?

Error message says Unable to resolve this.addGroups.  I've tried creating a sub list of groups and assigning it, and I have tried directly assigning with List.add

UPDATED FULL CLASS

```
public class GroupActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Context context;
RecyclerView groupRecyclerView;
GroupAdapter groupAdapter;
private Toolbar toolbar;

public List<Group> list = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_group);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("POLICE APP");

    context = this;
    Helpers.setTabs(context, this, 2);

    groupRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.ui_Groups_RecyclerView);
    this.GetData();
    groupAdapter = new GroupAdapter(this, list);

    groupRecyclerView.setAdapter(groupAdapter);
    groupRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


}

public void addGroups(List<Group> grps) {

    this.list = grps;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_group, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void GetData() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Group");

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        List<Group> sList;

        public void done(List<ParseObject> groupList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < groupList.size(); i++) {
                    try {
                        Group grp1 = new Group("1", groupList.get(i).getString("Name"), " Turn in your time sheets", "d");
                        sList.add(grp1);
                        Log.d("group1:", "inserted the group");
                    } catch (Exception c) {
                        c.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("group1:", c.getMessage().toString());
                    }
                }
                this.addGroups.add(sList);
                Log.d("groups1", "Retrieved " + groupList.size() + " groups");
            } else {
                Log.d("groups1", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }


        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: What is the visibility of list? public, private, protected?

Comment: List<Group> list = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Make list a field in super class. Declare it in header, outside from methods and make it private. Then use setter and my answer to fill it.

Comment: updated the code above

Comment: Updated answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

All subclasses can access all fields and methods from super class if they are not private. So, in your case, you have two options:

```
setList(clist); // I suppose list is private and in super class you made a setter for it

// or

this.list=cList;  // if list isn't private
```

**EDIT**

How I would make super class:

```
public class SuperClass{
   private List<Group> list;
   // class's methods
   public void setList(ArrayList<Group> list){
      this.list = list;
   }
}
```

**EDIT No2**

Inspired by your edited question ( :) ), I changed a bit your code and it should work. Test it and post results.

```
public class GroupActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Context context;
RecyclerView groupRecyclerView;
GroupAdapter groupAdapter;
private Toolbar toolbar;

public List<Group> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_group);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("POLICE APP");

    context = this;
    Helpers.setTabs(context, this, 2);

    groupRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.ui_Groups_RecyclerView);
    this.GetData();
    groupAdapter = new GroupAdapter(this, list);

    groupRecyclerView.setAdapter(groupAdapter);
    groupRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


}

public void addGroups(List<Group> grps) {

    this.list = grps;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_group, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void GetData() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Group");

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        List<Group> sList = new ArrayList<Group>();

        public void done(List<ParseObject> groupList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < groupList.size(); i++) {
                    try {
                        Group grp1 = new Group("1", groupList.get(i).getString("Name"), " Turn in your time sheets", "d");
                        sList.add(grp1);
                        Log.d("group1:", "inserted the group");
                    } catch (Exception c) {
                        c.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("group1:", c.getMessage().toString());
                    }
                }
                addGroups(sList);
                Log.d("groups1", "Retrieved " + groupList.size() + " groups");
            } else {
                Log.d("groups1", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }


        }
    });

}
}
```

You made some obvious coding mistakes, so that was the problem if I'm right. Try it.

Comment: I tried this, previously.        this.list.add(grp1);        It will not allow me to access this.list  ** cannot resolve symbol ***

Comment: Can you post the code of that class? This code must work. Compare them and find the differences.

Comment: Accept answer if it helped you :) This is correct as I see.

Comment: Updated answer. Take a look.

Comment: Wher are the obvious coding mistakes?  I found the answer....the code is fine, parse returns async and the list hasn't finished loading.  Thanks

Comment: You declare sList like List<Group> sList; and use it ( sList.add()) without initialization.
Then, this.addGroups.add(sList); what this .ADD() does? This are't mistakes?

If you succeeded, great. Doesn't matter the rest :D

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  I needed to add this code after the for loop.
             groupAdapter = new GroupAdapter(context, list);

```
    groupRecyclerView.setAdapter(groupAdapter);
```

Basically, Parse was returning async and the view didnt have the new content.  Just update the view after your for loop